# Convert hair particles to mesh and keep thickness

Tags: particles, hair

I have a plant and root ball I'm rendering, I used the hair particle system to make some roots.  When I convert the particles to a mesh though, there is no thickness.  How can I convert these roots to a mesh so I can export in glb and have everything show up?

[image: render of a taro plant]

Comment: I guess you need to convert your mesh to curve, give it thickness, then reconvert to mesh